# wso2 - Archive extraction failed. Cannot create directory

Tags: directory, wso2, archive, creation, wso2-business-process

During deploy on bps (on windows) I got the following error:

```
TID: [0] [BPS] [2015-11-13 17:45:17,601] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer} -  Error deploying BPEL package: myBPS-1.0.0.zip {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer}
java.lang.Exception: Archive extraction failed. Cannot create directory: C:\WSO2\WSO2BP~1.0\bin\..\repository\bpel\-1234\myBPS-1.0.0-186\xsd.
        at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.Utils.extractBPELArchive(Utils.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl.deploy(TenantProcessStoreImpl.java:237)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer.deploy(BPELDeployer.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.bpel.BPELAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(BPELAppDeployer.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:251)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

I've already tried to apply 777 on `C:\WSO2\` but it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look right: `\bin..\repository`; I suspect it should be `\bin\..\repository`.

Comment: I've fixed deleting the directory C:\WSO2\WSO2BP~1.0\bin\..\repository\bpel\-1234\myBPS-1.0.0-186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed deleting the directory C:\WSO2\WSO2BP~1.0\bin..\repository\bpel-1234\myBPS-1.0.0-186